# How to create a live USB of FreeBSD 11.1 from Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, freebsd, dd, live-usb

I'd like to boot a live USB for FreeBSD 11.1 in my UEFI firmware. I tried creating a live USB using:

```
dd if=FreeBSD-11.1-RELEASE-amd64-dvd1.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=4M status=progress && sync
```

Then I tried booting this USB and I got the GRUB message:

```
error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode.
grub rescue>
```

There's nothing wrong with this USB as I've managed to boot several distros from it and not that long ago (a month at most was the last time I did), with me placing those distros on the USB using much the same dd command.

I'm running Arch Linux and I do not have Windows, macOS or any non-Linux operating system installed so if your method involves using another operating system I'm afraid it is not applicable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong image. At the [Release Information page](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/11.1R/announce.html) of FreeBSD 11.1, you can get the following info:

> **dvd1**
>
> This contains everything necessary to install the base FreeBSD
>   operating system, the documentation, debugging distribution sets, and
>   a small set of pre-built packages aimed at getting a graphical
>   workstation up and running. It also supports booting into a "livefs"
>   based rescue mode. This should be all you need if you can burn and use
>   DVD-sized media.
>
> --- snip ---
>
> **memstick**
>
> This can be written to an USB memory stick (flash drive) and used to
>   do an install on machines capable of booting off USB drives. It also
>   supports booting into a "livefs" based rescue mode. There are no
>   pre-built packages.
>
> As one example of how to use the memstick image, assuming the USB
>   drive appears as /dev/da0 on your machine something like this should
>   work:
>
> ```
>     # dd if=FreeBSD-11.1-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img \
>       of=/dev/da0 bs=1m conv=sync
> ```
>
> Be careful to make sure you get the target (of=) correct.

So, you have things to fix/adapt to make this work with Linux:

- Image must be `FreeBSD-11.1-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img` not `dvd1`.
- Block size must be `bs=1m` not `4m` with `memstick` image. Use capital `M` on [Linux `dd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) to represent the 1024*1024 size, the same as by using `m` on [FreeBSD `dd`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?dd(1)).
- Change the output file to the one that represents you pendrive, like `of=/dev/sdc` as you have shown at the question.

Comment: On Linux USBs are always denoted as /dev/sd*X*, where X is the name of the drive. Thanks though, the dvd1 image works well in VirtualBox and as Linux ISO images always work on USBs if they work in VirtualBox (from my experience with almost a hundred distros) I assumed it'd be the same. Thanks for teaching me that my assumption was faulty. Once I confirm your solution works I shall accept.

Comment: Oh and by-the-way `bs=1m` doesn't work, what you were looking for was `bs=1M`, as with `1m` I get `dd: invalid number: ‘1m’`.

Comment: As i've quoted the documentation and tried to not change it. You will have to adapt that `of=` to the one that corresponds to your output device, that is probably `/dev/sdc`. I'll put that on the answer too. There is no problem on assume that an ISO file is hibrid(dvd and usb), but as a matter of curiosity,  that was not true also for Debian some years ago, where you had to use Unetbootin or other tools to extract iso contents ;). Virtualbox emulates the cd driver so, it shall work.

Comment: I probably wasn't a Linux user 'some years ago', depending on your definition of 'some'.

Comment: Right. and, use `1M` on Linux `dd` command ;)

Comment: Some years, means more than twice, less than ten....lol

Comment: It booted. It was partitioning that was my downfall. I set it up to install on a spare partition I had created from Linux with ZFS on it. It wouldn't accept it, I suspect ZFS on FreeBSD is a little different to the Linux equivalent. Then I got FreeBSD to install ZFS on it and it crashed (gave some error, should have written it down). Tried UFS too and it too crashed with the same error. (some def) With that definition then it's entirely possible I wasn't a Linux user back then, I've only been on it for 5 & 1/2 years.

Comment: You will need to read some documentation about partitions on FreeBSD. FreeBSD uses a concept called slices for UFS filesystem. Slices are the little pieces that we know as partitions on Linux and Windows. Inside those slices, you have pieces called partitions, and this could cause some confusion on newcomers(specially due this ambiguity of naming) - https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/disk-organization.html - Maybe, you have an Linux Extended partition only available to FreeBSD, and this could cause you some issues during the setup.

Comment: One question this didn't answer is whether setting up slices would require me to delete my other existing partitions (the ones with Linux on them). Also most guides seem to pertain to MBR. I suppose I should ask this elsewhere.

Comment: It depends on how many partitions you already have allocated to Linux. It also depends if using EFI+GPT or pure MBR disks(with no GPT). With MBR you will be limited to 4 primary partitions, and if you have used them with Linux(say, /, /home, swap and /opt for example), or 3 primary and 1 extended on Linux, you will not be able to create more partitions(FreeBSD Slices). It just depends on your setup...